# Unreal Engine Failed to initialize ShaderCodeLibrary

Tags: visual-studio-code, shader, nvidia, vulkan, unreal-engine5

EDIT1:
This problem also apears on windows so I think it is a general problem with unreal engine 5 and visual studio code.

I am trying to debug a unreal engine 5 project. When running DebugGame I get the error message:

> Failed to initialize ShaderCodeLibrary required by the project because
> part of the Global shader library is missing

I am using:
Linux, wayland, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060, Visual Studio Code

More Logs:

```
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:210][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Using Device 0: Geometry 1 BufferAtomic64 1 ImageAtomic64 1
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:211][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Found 3 Queue Families
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:211][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Initializing Queue Family 0: 16 queues Gfx Compute Xfer Sparse
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:211][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Initializing Queue Family 1: 2 queues Xfer Sparse
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:211][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Skipping unnecessary Queue Family 2: 8 queues Compute Xfer Sparse
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Using device layers
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Using device extensions
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: * VK_KHR_driver_properties
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: * VK_KHR_get_memory_requirements2
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: * VK_KHR_dedicated_allocation
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: * VK_KHR_create_renderpass2
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: * VK_KHR_fragment_shading_rate
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: * VK_KHR_swapchain
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: * VK_KHR_maintenance1
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: * VK_KHR_maintenance2
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: * VK_EXT_memory_budget
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: * VK_KHR_shader_atomic_int64
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: * VK_EXT_shader_image_atomic_int64
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: * VK_KHR_image_format_list
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: * VK_EXT_shader_viewport_index_layer
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Max memory allocations -1.
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: 3 Device Memory Heaps:
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:   0: Flags 0x1 - Size 6442450944 (6144.00 MB) - Used 0 (0.00%) - DeviceLocal - PrimaryHeap
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:   1: Flags 0x0 - Size 12117417984 (11556.07 MB) - Used 0 (0.00%)
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:   2: Flags 0x1 - Size 257949696 (246.00 MB) - Used 0 (0.00%) - DeviceLocal
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: 5 Device Memory Types (Not unified):
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:   1: Flags 0x00001 - Heap  0 -  DeviceLocal                                         
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:   0: Flags 0x00000 - Heap  1 -                                                      
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:   2: Flags 0x00006 - Heap  1 -              HostVisible HostCoherent                
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:   3: Flags 0x0000e - Heap  1 -              HostVisible HostCoherent HostCached     
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:   4: Flags 0x00007 - Heap  2 -  DeviceLocal HostVisible HostCoherent                
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Memory Budget Extension:
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:             | Usage                      | Budget           | Size             |
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:    ---------|------------------------------------------------------------------|
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:     HEAP 00 |   0.00% /          0.19 MB |       3432.00 MB |       6144.00 MB |
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:     HEAP 01 |   0.17% /         19.27 MB |      11556.07 MB |      11556.07 MB |
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:     HEAP 02 |  18.60% /         45.75 MB |        200.25 MB |        246.00 MB |
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:586][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:    ---------|------------------------------------------------------------------|
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:622][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: FVulkanPipelineStateCacheManager: Binary pipeline cache '../../../../../../../opt/unreal-engine/../../home/walde/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject9/Saved/VulkanPSO.cache.10de.1f15' not found.
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:623][  0]LogVulkanRHI:     Adapter Name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:623][  0]LogVulkanRHI:      API Version: 1.3.205
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:623][  0]LogVulkanRHI:   Driver Version: 515.65
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:635][  0]LogRHI: Texture pool is 4473 MB (70% of 6390 MB)
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:641][  0]LogRendererCore: Ray tracing is disabled. Reason: r.RayTracing=0.
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:641][  0]LogShaderLibrary: Display: Running without a pakfile and did not find a monolithic library 'Global' - attempting disk search for its chunks
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:642][  0]LogShaderLibrary: Display:    ....  not found
[2022.08.24-09.17.36:643][  0]LogShaderLibrary: Error: Failed to initialize ShaderCodeLibrary required by the project because part of the Global shader library is missing from ../../../../../../../opt/unreal-engine/../../home/walde/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject9/Content/.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run DebugGame it will go and look for files in your binary folders to run your game. If you've not gone to File > Package project, you are likely not to have the required files. The package process creates these files. Be sure that you go into Package settings and select the appropriate target (for example, if you're trying to launch Debug Game, then you should change it from the default of Shipping to Debug Game)